# OSX Autolayout Fails to Redraw Some Controls As Window Gets Smaller

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I've got an xib file for a view that uses autolayout. As the view is made larger, the 3 buttons that are placed along the lower edge of the window all move down as expected, maintaining a constant distance to the lower edge of the window. But as the window is made smaller, the three buttons don't move, eventually disappear and only when the window is made bigger (by even the tiniest amount) do they get redrawn. The animated gif below shows how it looks. **UPDATE: This is a newer screen capture. Notice that not only the buttons but also the segmented control does not draw properly as the window resizes.**

[image]

The constraints are where I'd been focused. For example, the button marked "Check All" has 2 constraints that relate to its vertical position. The other two have to do with leading edge placement and I've not included them here.

A commenter requested that I provide detailed information about the constraints. The first image shows the constraints on the "Check All" button. (The other button has similar constraints.). The constraints are all priority 1000, and they are slightly different from what was in the original post.

[image]

This next screenshot shows the constraints on the table above the Check All button.

[image]

I have this code on the app delegate:

```
- (void) windowDidResize: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    _masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)_window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

If I explicitly add code to this method to redraw the buttons and segmented control that are not drawing properly, everything looks great. That works around the problem, but it still doesn't explain why this happens. **UPDATE: It says to me this is probably not an autolayout issue as I originally suspected but something to do with the redraw cycle.**

Does anyone have an idea about why this might be behaving as it does?

Comment: Do you have any custom view classes which (accidentally?) override any of the `NSView` methods relating to auto layout or frame setting (e.g. `-layout`, `-layoutSubtreeIfNeeded`, or `-setFrame...`)? Similarly, are you using a custom subclass of `NSWindow` that does anything like that? Is anything being logged to the console as you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I didn't override any of those methods or things like that. I did have something that calling NSLog on the resize notification and I removed it. No change in behavior of the app, however.

Comment: I finally got a workaround by changing the windowDidResize to invoke `-setNeedsDisplay: YES` for each control that's not being redrawn properly when the window shrinks. The problem remains unresolved but this temporarily makes things work.

Comment: Could you also add screenshots of the autolayout constraints?

Comment: Autolayout constraints added. It would appear from what I've observed that perhaps this has nothing or little to do with autolayout settings and more to do with when the autolayout code redraws the controls.

Comment: Generally, when using auto layout, you do not set view frames. So, your `-windowDidResize:` method is very suspicious. Is the view controlled by `_masterViewController` laid out by auto layout? If so, why do you feel the need to set its frame and did you turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for it? If it's not laid out using auto layout, why? And why are you not using the autoresizing mask to have it resize with its superview (which was the norm before auto layout)?

Comment: @KenThomases, you ask some great questions. I started with a sample app (from Apple, I think), as an example. It didn't support autolayout. I then enabled it: xib has Use Auto Layout checked, as well as Autoresizes Subviews and Translates Mask... With all that, if I remove the `-windowDidResize:` method, then all autolayout stops working. What am I missing?

Comment: Unchecking Translates Mask... has everything spaced properly, from the bottom left corner, but I can't get anything to grow to fill up to the top of the superview.

Comment: You have a view controller. So, you're presumably loading and adding a view from a separate NIB to your window. When you do that, you should: a) disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` if it wasn't disabled in the NIB, and b) add constraints to relate the view to its new superview (after it has been added to that superview). For example, if you want it to fill the superview, you would use the visual format language strings `@"|[view]|"` and `@"V:|[view]|"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, wherever it is that you do the equivalent of `[_window.contentView addSubview:_masterViewController.view]`, you should do the following:

```
[_window.contentView addSubview:_masterViewController.view];
_masterViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // optional if you already turned it off in the NIB
NSDictionary* views = @{ @"view": _masterViewController.view };
NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:views];
[_window.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                                      options:0
                                                      metrics:nil
                                                        views:views];
[_window.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
```

Those constraints will keep `_masterViewController.view` filling the window's content view.

Comment: Thanks! Just for my curiosity, can this only be achieved through code? I assume it can't be done in IB because code is being used to glue the view and superview. Right?

Comment: Constraints can only be set up in a NIB for views which are already in the same view hierarchy (in the NIB).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding align Center to Y for those 2(check/uncheck) buttons. Set it to the Transmit button which will also have bottom space to superview.

Basically check/uncheck button should just have height and width constraints plus the align center to Y constraints which is set to the transmit button. Also there should be a constraint between check and uncheck button(leading space one)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added all the constraints you suggested, to no avail.